# How to show only one row from a column in MySQL based on another Table - Express JS

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I have created a simple CRUD application with ExpressJS and MySQL. What I am trying to do is to show the "Users Name" of a specified post, based on which user created that post.

I have 2 tables... posts & users. The posts table has an author column that fills with the users ID when a post is created.

I am able to make the specific "Post" show its data based on the post ID (i.e Post Title & Post Body). However when I try to show the "Users Name" based on which user created that specific post it shows every "Users Name" inside of the users table.

Can anyone help me so that when I view a specific post it will only show the correct "Users Name" based on the posts that that user has created?

My code is below:

posts.js

```
// Read A Post
router.get('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    let sql = `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = ${req.params.id}`;
    let query = db.query(sql, (error, result) => {
        if(error) throw error;
        db.query(`SELECT name FROM users`, (error, userName) => {
            if(error) throw error;
            res.render('post', {
                posts: result,
                author: userName
            });
        });
    });
});
```

posts.pug

```
extends layout

block content
    ul.list-group
        each post in posts
            li.list-group-item
                h1= JSON.stringify(post.title)
                h3= JSON.stringify(author)
                p= JSON.stringify(post.body)
            a.btn.btn-primary.float-right(href='/posts/update/' + post.id) Update
            a.btn.btn-danger.float-right(href='/posts/delete/' + post.id) Delete
```

posts Schema

```
Field   Type    Null    Key Default Extra
id      int(11) NO      PRI NULL    auto_increment
title   varchar(255)    YES NULL        
body    varchar(255)    YES NULL        
author  varchar(255)    YES NULL
```

users Schema

```
Field     Type         Null        Key    Default     Extra
id        int(11)       NO         PRI    NULL        auto_increment
name      varchar(255)  YES               NULL  
email     varchar(255)  YES               NULL  
username  varchar(255)  YES               NULL  
password  varchar(255)  YES               NULL
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This is not specific to node, but a rudimentary SQL question. Post your database schema please.

Comment: Thanks, I added the Schema. I am new to all this so I hope I posted correctly what you asked for. @RobertMoskal

Comment: The schema won't quite work together.  You do need a foreign key in posts that comes from users.  It should probably be the id and not the name (unless you are making that unique.

Comment: Thanks @RobertMoskal. I was able to make it work without a foreign key but I am pretty sure the way I have it setup is not efficient but for the sake of learning this will do for now. I am kind of familiar with Primary and Foreign keys but I would love to learn more. Do you have a good article you can suggest where I can read up more on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the code you make 2 independent queries:
1) select relevant posts
2) select all users

use the Inner Join to achieve what you want.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

your code will look smth like this:

```
// Read A Post
router.get('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    let sql = `SELECT * FROM posts INNER JOIN users ON posts.userid= users.id WHERE posts.id = ${req.params.id} `;
    let query = db.query(sql, (error, result) => {
        if(error) throw error;
            res.render('post', {
                posts: result,
                author: result
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to make it work. I made my query as you suggested: SELECT * FROM posts INNER JOIN users ON posts.author = users.id WHERE posts.id = ${req.params.id}. Then inside my pug file I added this loop: each authors in author. Then I changed the display like so: h3= JSON.stringify(authors.name)